# MonadTransControl instance for ProxyFast/ProxyCorrect

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, haskell-pipes

Using pipes, I'm trying to write an instance of [MonadTransControl](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monad-control/0.3.2.1/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html) for the [ProxyFast](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pipes/3.3.0/doc/html/Control-Proxy-Core-Fast.html) or [ProxyCorrect](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pipes/3.3.0/doc/html/Control-Proxy-Core-Correct.html) type. This is what I've got:

```
instance MonadTransControl (ProxyFast a' a b' b) where
  data StT (ProxyFast a' a b' b) a = StProxy { unStProxy :: ProxyFast a' a b' b Identity a}
  liftWith = undefined
  restoreT = undefined
```

I have no idea how to write liftWith or restoreT. The instances for the other monad transformers all use a function that "swaps" the monads, for example EitherT e m a -> m (EitherT e Identity a), but I couldn't find any such function in pipes. How does the instance for MonadTransControl for ProxyCorrect / ProxyFast look like? Or is it impossible to write one? (If yes, is it possible in pipes 4.0?)

Comment: I never understood `MonadTransControl`.  Is there some tutorial or blog post that explains how to use it?

Comment: I could only find http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2011/08/monad-control

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the link, and now I can give a better answer.

No, there is no way to implement this, using either version of `pipes`.  The reason why is that `MonadTransControl` expects a monad transformer to be built on top of a single layer of the underlying base monad.  This is true for all the monad transformers that `MonadTransControl` currently implements, such as:

```
ErrorT  ~ m (Either e r)
StateT  ~ s -> m (r, s)
WriterT ~ m (r, w)
ReaderT ~ i -> m r
ListT   ~ m [r]  -- This version of ListT is wrong, and the true ListT
                 -- would not work for `MonadTransControl`
```

However, a `Proxy` does not wrap a single layer of the base monad.  This is true for both `pipes` versions where you can nest as many layers of the base monad as you want.

In fact, any monad transformer that nests the base monad multiple times will defy a `MonadTransControl` instance, such as:

```
FreeT     -- from the `free` package
ListT     -- when done "right"
ConduitM  -- from the `conduit` package
```

However, just because `pipes` does not implement `MonadTransControl` doesn't mean that all hope is lost.  `pipes-safe` implements many of the operations that one would typically expect from `MonadTransControl`, such as `bracket`ing resource acquisitions, so if you can elaborate on your specific use case I can tell you more if there is an appropriate `pipes`-based solution for your problem.

Comment: Rhanks for the answer. You're right, I was searching for pipes-safe.