# A MonadTransControl instance for FreeT

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, free-monad

Is it possible to implement a [`MonadTransControl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-0.3.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html#t%3aMonadTransControl) instance for [`FreeT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.7.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Free.html#t%3aFreeT)? I started with the following, but got stuck:

```
instance (Functor f) => MonadTransControl (FreeT f) where
  newtype StT (FreeT f) r = FreeTStT r
  liftWith unlift = lift $ unlift $ error "Stuck here"
  restoreT inner = do
    FreeTStT r <- lift inner
    return r
```

If it is unimplementable, than why and is it possible to extend a specific free functor implementation somehow to make it implementable?

Comment: Looking at the `MonadTransControl` instances for other types it seems that `StT (FreeT f) r` should be something like `FreeTStT (Free f r)`. Otherwise you don't capture any "monadic state of `FreeT f`" or make use of `f`.

Comment: And with that implementation of `StT` it should be clear how to define `liftWith` and `restoreT`.

Comment: You may want to read this other [question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511841/monadtranscontrol-instance-for-proxyfast-proxycorrect/17515535#17515535) which seem related.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez In other words, it's impossible?

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: turns out you need `Traversable f` constraint for `MonadTransControl` instance.*

***Warning: the instance in this answer does not obey all the laws of `MonadTransControl`***

### Pragmas and imports

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import qualified Data.Traversable as T
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.Control
import Control.Monad.Trans.Free
import qualified Control.Monad.Free as F
```

### Free monadic state

As I said in comments, the proper "monadic state" of `FreeT f` should be `Free f` (the one from `Control.Monad.Free`):

```
instance T.Traversable f => MonadTransControl (FreeT f) where
  newtype StT (FreeT f) a = StTFreeT { getStTFreeT :: F.Free f a }
```

Now the implementation of `restoreT` changes a bit:

```
  restoreT inner = do
    StTFreeT m <- lift inner
    F.toFreeT m
```

### `liftWith` implementation

Before we look at the implementation let's see what should the type of `liftWith` be:

```
liftWith :: Monad m => (Run (FreeT f) -> m a) -> FreeT f m a
```

And `Run (FreeT f)` is actually

```
forall n b. Monad n => FreeT f n b -> n (StTFreeT f b)
```

So the implementation would be like that:

```
liftWith unlift = lift $ unlift (liftM StTFreeT . pushFreeT)
```

The rest is simple:

```
pushFreeT :: (T.Traversable f, Monad m) => FreeT f m a -> m (F.Free f a)
pushFreeT m = do
  f <- runFreeT m
  case f of
    Pure x -> return (return x)
    Free y -> liftM wrap $ T.mapM pushFreeT y
```

### Why `Traversable`?

As you can see the problem is with `pushFreeT` function: it uses `T.mapM` (which is `traverse` but with `Monad` constraint). Why do we need it there? If you look at the definition of `FreeT` you may notice that *(NB: this is rough, I forget about `Pure` here)*:

```
FreeT f m a ~ m (f (m (f ... )))
```

And as a result of `pushFreeT` we need `m (Free f a)`:

```
m (Free f a) ~ m (f (f (f ... )))
```

So we need to "push" all `f`s to the end and join all `m`s in the head. Thus we need an operation that lets us push a single `f` through single `m` and this is exactly what `T.mapM pushFreeT` gives us:

```
mapM :: (Monad m, Traversable t) => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m (t b)
mapM pushFreeT :: Traversable t => t (FreeT t m a) -> m (t (Free t a))
```

### The laws

Every class instance usually come with laws. `MonadTransControl` is not an exception, so let's check if they hold for this instance:

```
liftWith . const . return = return
liftWith (const (m >>= f)) = liftWith (const m) >>= liftWith . const . f
```

These two laws obviously follow from laws for `MonadTrans` and the definition of `liftWith`.

```
liftWith (\run -> run t) >>= restoreT . return = t
```

Apparently, this law **does not hold**. This is because monad layers in `t` are collapsed when we `pushFreeT`. So the implemented `liftWith` merges effects in all layers of `FreeT f m` leaving us with the equivalent of `m (Free f)`.

Comment: Thanks. While this all makes perfect sense, it seems impossible to implement an instance of `Traversable`. E.g., how would you deal with a trivial functor such as `data IOF z = PutStrLn String z | GetArg (String -> z)`? 

While `PutStrLn` operation makes no problem, an operation which requires evaluation such as `GetArg` makes it impossible to implement the "traverse" operation.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov AFAICT it is possible to TH-generate instances for functors where argument has only **strictly positive** occurrences (such as `String -> a` or `a` or `(Int, Either a String)` but not `(a -> r) -> r)`). Would you like to see that kind of solution?

Comment: @NikitaVolkov I've updated my answer to reflect the fact that this instance can not obey one of `MonadTransControl` laws. So as [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511841/monadtranscontrol-instance-for-proxyfast-proxycorrect/17515535#17515535) suggests, there can be no correct instance for `FreeT`.